# Exporting multiple .fbx files from Blender

Tags: export, blender

I have looked at forum posts and looked at code from forums/git and I just cannot figure this out on how to get all the meshes in my Blender project to be exported into separate files instead of 1 .fbx file.  Like I have arms, legs, body, jewelry all in one project but I would like multiple files each with 1 mesh instead of all the meshes being combined into 1 file.

I am not trying to learn a lot about Blender by any means as I just work in Unity.  I just need to know how to do this 1 time and I probably will never use Blender again.

So the forum posts that I keep coming across are usually, "Here is this code snippet to get what you want" and that is it.  I have no idea where to go to put this code, how to get it to work or anything.  I have yet to see a forum post that gives a simple step by step to get something like I want to work.  I am very very ignorant with Blender and today is literally the first time I have used and I have wasted more than enough time on this so I am coming here.

I was going to try this [here](https://github.com/pjezek/blender/blob/master/unity_tools/__init__.py) but I don't even know how to test it to see if it even works.

I have a feeling what I want is probably the epitome of easy for blender users but like I said, I'm very ignorant with it and I need help.

So my Stack Overflowians, I call upon thee to smite thy ignorance of thou blender!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the number of objects is small you can manually export each model. Select one object then *File->Export->FBX*, in the options available when specifying the file there is a *Selection Only* option that will only export object/s that are selected which allows you to select and export one object to each file.

[image: fbx export options]

If you have a lot of objects to export, then the addon you linked to can automate the export process. While it is setup as a multi file addon it only has one file, probably planning for future additions. You can view the [raw file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pjezek/blender/master/unity_tools/__init__.py) at github and save it with a different name, say unity.py. In the [addon section](https://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/addons.html) of the blender preferences there is a button to *Install From File...*. After selecting the file you saved, enable the addon and then in the 3DView toolshelf <kbd>T</kbd> you will find a misc tab that contains the panel for the addon. Set the output filepath and click *Batch Export* to export each object to it's own file.

[image: unity tools panel]

Comment: Thank you sambler for the answer and it was quick and easy!  *inserts You da real mvp meme*

Comment: Wow, but this addon does some damage.. All the batched models share the origin point of each and every one of them, that is a no go, if you want (and you want) to have origin point set at origin of each object.